# Redirect API requests with path, parameters, body and headers

Tags: php, laravel, apache, cpanel

I have changed hosting provider and got new domain.

I want to redirect the old API to the new API, how can I achieve that without effecting the mobile app?

Example:

```
https://old.example.com/api/example
```

To

```
https://new.example.app/api/example
```

With all request path, parameters, body and headers

Comment: I assume you're talking about the API to control [cPanel](https://api.docs.cpanel.net/) or [aaPanel](https://www.aapanel.com/Document/api.pdf)? You cannot just redirect API calls, these two API's are completely different. You need to rewrite your code.

Comment: Or do you just mean you've changed hosting providers and got a new domain name? Or what? The question lacks context and proper information and so is very unclear. See [ask] and try again.

Comment: I've changed hosting providers, and updated the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks. Does the old domain name still exist? Do you still own it?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to redirect the old API to the new API [...] [w]ith all request path, parameters, body and headers

In terms of a HTTP redirect, the old server needs to give a redirect response (in your case I'd suggest a *permanent* 301 redirect; [HTTP 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)).

A HTTP redirect allows you to pass the new domain name along with the path (a.k.a. resource) and parameters (a.k.a. query).

An API client then needs to re-send (as it has been redirected by the 301 response to the new URL) the request which then should be with path, parameters, body and headers.

A mobile would then not be affected (the mobile app is the client) in so-far it supports HTTP redirects.

But there is a caveat: While even very old HTTP clients have not problems with GET requests and redirects, the behaviour for POST or PUT requests may vary across clients and implementations. An example would be that the request method would change from POST to GET as well as that the body or the original request headers would not be re-send.

In your scenario this depends on the HTTP client that is in use within the mobile app. In case running the scenario in your test bed ([Testbed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testbed)) reveals the mobile app does not behave transparently with the redirects, you need to conduct a better strategy.

What most often is possible is to make the old endpoint act as a reverse proxy to the new endpoint with no changes for the client. The old domain / api then acts as intermediate client forwarding the request (with all the relevant headers and the body) to the new endpoint, waiting for the response and then forwarding the response to the client. This is also similar to an API Gateway (or more precisely it is an API Gateway then, just with only a limited set of functionality only, that is only for forwarding the request to the new endpoint).

> Despite the tons of examples and docs, mod_rewrite is voodoo. Damned
> cool voodoo, but still voodoo.
>
> -- [Brian Moore](https://web.archive.org/web/19970405074812/http://www.cmc.net/%7Ebem/)

The **Apache HTTP server** is a full-featured application server and can act as such an API Gateway (both for the redirects alone or the reverse proxy). You can find more information with the **proxy module**, a good starting place is perhaps the *[Forward Proxies and Reverse Proxies/Gateways](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse)* section.

There is also a good share of flexibility with the powerful **rewrite module** (the Swiss Army Knife of URL
manipulation; mind the [`P|proxy` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p)) that perhaps already has crossed your ways and conceptually may already has been probed within your testbed for the HTTP redirect scenario suggested in the beginning of the answer (mind the [`R|redirect` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)).